# How long do hats usually take to be awarded?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

I voted on a question and answer for the **I am your Father** hat, but it has not been immediately awarded. Are people aware of any regular window of time for hat counts to be updated?

Comment: Totally voting on this to get that hat :)

Comment: it's kinda funny, reading this question and then seeing the avatar!

Comment: Six to eight weeks?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[A Stack Overflow employee confirmed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288590/how-to-get-hats/288591#comment936759_288591) that the script runs **every 10 minutes**. (In previous editions of Winter Bash, it used to be 5 minutes.) Of course, that makes the expected delay between a 'hat trigger' and you being informed 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Glorfindel. I'd forgotten that meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange were different. Perhaps my question was better suited for meta.stackexchange?

Comment: Nope, you can get support here as well. [You're not the only one here with questions about Winter Bash](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winterbash-2016).

Answer (score 5):

Empirical data has shown that this hat was awarded after ~5 minutes. 
I'm unaware of what inner-workings led to this, but at least there's one data point.

Comment: Is this a long way of saying "Arrived 4.5 minutes later, go figure"?